# NumberFormatter RoundingMode with unusual round

Tags: swift

Making my own formatter like this:

```
enum Formatters {
enum Number {
    static let moneyFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let mFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        mFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.currency
        mFormatter.currencyGroupingSeparator = " "
        mFormatter.roundingMode = NumberFormatter.RoundingMode.halfUp
        mFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
        return mFormatter
    }()
}
```

}

And want to example: if 11 400 then round to 11 000, if 11 500 then 12 000
And etc. But it RoundMode works only with Digits correctly, how it setup for groups?

Answer (score 3):

`NumberFormatter` has a `roundingIncrement` property for this purpose:

```
enum Formatters {
    enum Number {
        static let moneyFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
            let mFormatter = NumberFormatter()
            mFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
            mFormatter.roundingMode = .halfUp
            mFormatter.roundingIncrement = 1_000
            mFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
            return mFormatter
        }()
    }
}

let fmt = Formatters.Number.moneyFormatter

print(fmt.string(from: 10_499.99)!) // 10.000 €
print(fmt.string(from: 10_500.00)!) // 11.000 €
```

However, for some reason unknown to me, this does not work if the
`groupingSeparator` or `currencyGroupingSeparator` property is set. Therefore, if you need a non-default grouping separator, you would
have to replace it "manually" in the formatted string.

Of course an alternative is to round the value to the nearest
multiple of 1,000 *before* formatting it. Example:

```
let value = 10_499.99
let roundedToThousands = (value / 1000).rounded() * 1000
```