# How to use NumberFormatter to keep front number of the same position, and back zero?

Tags: ios, swift, number-formatting

I have a number array, and I want to use NumberFormatter to convert the same rule to show.
How to practice this feature?

```
var inputArray: [Double] = [1396140.0, 930760.0, 465380.0, 0.0]
```

and I want to output like this:

```
var outputArray1: [Double] = [1500000.0, 1000000.0, 500000.0, 0.0]
var outputArray2: [Double] = [1600000.0, 1060000.0, 530000.0, 0.0]
```

Thanks.

Comment: This might be what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44660726.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NumberFormatter RoundingMode with unusual round](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44660726/numberformatter-roundingmode-with-unusual-round)